# Are join and return the inverse of each other?

Tags: haskell, monads

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory says

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
join x = x >>= id
```

Is `id`  the identity functor on category `Hask` and does `id` have type `a-> a`?

`>>=` requires its second argument to have type `a->ma`, and if `id` has type `a-> a`, how can `id` be used as the second argument of `>>=`?

`return` has type `a -> ma`.
Are `join` and `return` the inverse of each other?

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with your whitespace; `a -> m a` and `a -> ma` are two entirely different types.

Comment: `id` is the identity *function* *in* **Hask**; `data Identity a = Identity a` is the identity *functor on* **Hask**.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What is the difference between `m a` and `ma`? (2) What is the difference between " the identity function" in Hask and " the identity functor " on Hask? (3) Does `data Identity a = Identity a` define a type `Identity` which has a single constructor also named as `Identity` and parameterized by a type variable `a`? How does that mean it is the identity functor on Hask?

Comment: 1) `a -> ma` is just `a -> b` using a different name. In `a -> m a`, `m` has kind `* -> *`, so it has to be applied to some other type in order to provide a valid return type. 2) One is a function, the other is a functor. 3) `Identity` is, indeed, just a very simple type constructor. Its functor instance is likewise simple: `instance Functor Identity where fmap f (Identity x) = Identity (f x)`. By itself, `Identity` is not very useful, but it serves as useful base for things like monad stacks (since `Identity` is also a basic monad).

Comment: (For example, whereas something like `data State s a = ...` used to be defined directly, it is now defined as the `StateT` monad transformer applied to the `Identity` monad.)

Comment: Where (which book) did you and can I learn the declaration of `Identity`?

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure there's any book that would satisfy you, the `Identity` functor certainly isn't interesting enough to write a book about! The few brief paragraphs of the [hackage documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) are about as much as can reasonably be said. Oh and there's also this [excellent blog post](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/04/trivial-monad.html) about it, which is useful mainly just as an introduction to monads. And try reading about monad transformers, since that's the only real use case for the `Identity` monad.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, not the only one! It's also important for `lens`, and for similar reasons it's used to simplify `mergeA` to `merge` in `Data.Map.Merge` and `Data.IntMap.Merge`, and to simplify `replicateA` to `replicate` in `Data.Sequence`. It's also essential to the definition of `Data.Traversable.fmapDefault`. Then there are uses with `dependent-sum`, `dependent-map` (hence `reflex`), `vinyl`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

> `>>=` requires its second argument to have type `a->ma`, and if `id` has type `a-> a`, how can `id` be used as the second argument of `>>=`?

No, `>>=` requires its second argument to have type `a -> m b`, with `b` not necessarily equal to `a`. In the case you mention, we chose `a = m b` so that

```
(>>=) :: m (m b) -> (m b -> m b) -> m b
```

`id` can then be passed as the second parameter of type `m b -> m b`.

> `return` has type `a -> ma`. Are `join` and `return` the inverse of each other?

Not really, since we do not have `join :: m a -> a`.

It is true, though, that if we consider the special case `a = m b`, then

```
return :: m b -> m (m b)
join   :: m (m b) -> m b
```

and we do have `join . return = id`.

Even in that special case, we still do not have `return . join = id`, e.g. in the list monad:

```
return (join [[1],[2]]) = return [1,2] = [[1,2]]
```

Comment: Thanks. `join` has type `m (m a) -> m a`. How is that different from `ma -> a`?

Comment: @Tim For instance, in the list monad, you can apply `join` to a list of lists, but not to a list of non-lists. `join [True]` is a type error.

Comment: It's actually a pretty fundamental point about monads. They let you embed an arbitrary value inside the monad (with `return`) and flatten the outer layer in a nested monad (that's `join`), but there is *no* way, in general, to "remove" an item from the monad. (`>>=`, which is just a combination of `fmap` and `join`, does let you pretend to access the values inside, but only if you feed them to a function which returns a monadic value.) That's actually very important in the case of `IO`, Haskell's purity would be destroyed if there was a function `IO a -> a`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, I wonder if parsers offer an even better example: `Parser a -> a` may be more obviously absurd to someone coming from an imperative background.

Comment: Thanks. How does `join [[1],[2]]` work? `join` expects argument to have type `m( m b)`, while `[[1],[2]]` has type `m(m b)`? (`[[1,2]]` has type `m(m b)`.)

Comment: @Tim Both have type `[[Int]]` (assuming integer numerals for simplicity). Here `m=[]` and `b=Int`. They are different values of the same type.

Comment: `join [[1], [2]]` is `[1, 2]` - `join` for the list monad is exactly the same as `concat`. `m` here is the list constructor `[]` (and the type `[] a` is by convention and special syntax written as `[a]`) and taking `b` as `Int`, then the type is `[[Int]] -> [Int]`, that is `[] [] Int -> [] Int`, which is exactly `m (m b) -> m b`

Comment: `join` is defined as `join m = do x <- m; x`. So shouldn't `join [[1], [2]]` be evaluated to `[1], [2]`, why to `[1,2]`?